# How to create a click event on a label in uiScrollview in swift

Tags: swift

I've created a view dynamically with quite a bit of complexity:
There is a uiView inside a uiScrollView and there are 10 uiLabel inside it.
I'm trying to create a click event on uiLabel, but it doesn't work.
But if I attach a click event to uiScrollView, it works, but I don't know which uiLabel was clicked. How can I make a uiLabel clickable and check which uiLabel was clicked?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])
        
        let contentView = UIView()
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),
            contentView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
        ])
        
        var labelArray = [UILabel]()

        for i in 0..<10 {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = "Label \(i+1)"
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            contentView.addSubview(label)
            
            labelArray.append(label)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: CGFloat(50 * i + 20)),
                label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
                label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
                label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ])
            
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(labelTapped(_:)))
            label.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
            label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
    
    @objc func labelTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("clicked")
        if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
            print("Tapped Label: \(label.text ?? "")")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `UI(Tap)GestureRecognizer` has a `view` property which represents the view the gesture is attached to.

Comment: It works.  If it doesn't work, the problem is caused by something that you don't show in code.

Comment: @El Tomato : It works if you attach a click event to the upper uiScrollview.
But if you do that, you won't know which uiLabel was clicked.

Comment: You set a tag to the label.  So what's the issue?  Besides, you don't show a single line of code indicating that you use `UIScrollView`.  If you don't show us all relevant lines of code, that's all you get.

Comment: @El Tomato : I added code that doesn't work

Comment: Your `sender.view` is contentView.

Comment: @El Tomato:print("clicked") is also not called

Comment: @bomdong2230 I've edited my answer.  Whether or not it works for you, that's all you get from me.

Comment: @El Tomato : It still doesn't work, but thank you so much for thinking about it with me.

Comment: All right.  Good luck...  It works for me, though.

Comment: @bomdong2230 Simply add `UIButton` with same constraints of label and using tag know which button is clicked...